# HTML Problem: form causing line break before (Rails button_to)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms

The button_to causes a line break before it in HTML. I have [found a workaround which will work](http://ror.leewbutler.com/2008/04/xdressed-clickables.html), but it's hardly ideal, because then the buttons are NOT real buttons. Is there any other way to avoid the line break before the form?

Here's the resulting HTML

```
<a href="/last_page">Back</a> | 
<form method="post" action="/next_page" class="button-to">
<div><input type="submit" value="Continue" /></div>
</form>
```

**any help from the CSS side or the Rails side would really help!**

Comment: Hi Mike. Thanks for your question. Rails makes it that way. It turns out the DIV is not the problem, the form is (at least in my testing).

Comment: Is it set to display: block ?

Comment: Alex, yeah, there it is, it's now inline-block and that works.

Comment: It has to be in a div according to HTML: putting an <input> directly inside <form> isn't valid.

Comment: wow, doesn't that make 50% of the web incorrect? Thanks for the comments everybody.

Comment: Damn should of added an answer not a comment!

Comment: @Alex, if you make it an answer I'll mark it best answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure the CSS for that div is set to

```
display: inline;
```

Answer (score 14):

To only affect the button_to class and its inner div:

```
.button_to {
  display: inline;
}

.button_to div {
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: That's strange, I've seen that somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

the button_to creates an HTML < form > element, which is a block element in HTML. If you give the form a class or id, you build your css selector to get the form and use:

```
form {
display: inline
}
```

Comment: thanks, Rails gives it a class automatically, so your solution works.

Answer (score 3):

Got it from somewhere out there. Happily:

```
.button-to { display:inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 2):

None of these options worked for me on Rails 3.2.3 !
I found a working solution at http://www.deploymentzone.com/2011/12/07/button_to-urlhelpers-all-in-a-row/

Here it is:

```
/* ./app/assets/stylesheets/button_to.css.scss */

form.button_to {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:inline;
}

form.button_to div, form.button_to div input {
    display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You still have to specify inline for the div and the form.

```
div {
  display: inline;
}

.button-to {
  display: inline;
}
```

Wouldn't it be nicer if class="button-to" was also specified in the div ? or am I missing something ?

Comment: yes, otherwise you affect all your divs, which is definitely a problem-waiting-to-happen...

Answer (score 0):

A button_to generates a form and a div around the button. So, if you do not restrict the width of the container which is before the button, it will take 100% of the width pushing the button down.

```
<% @post.bids.each do |bid| %>
  <p>
    <div style="float: left; width: auto;"><%= bid.user.email %></div>   
    <%= button_to "Offer Bid", offer_bid_post_bid_path(@post, bid), :action => "offer_bid" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That's a good explanation of the problem, but doesn't offer a specific solution.